# What function gives XXeY in java?

Tags: java

What function in java gives you the output of these:

05e0

01e1

42e0

66e6

I've tried exp() and expm() but doesn't give the right answer.

Comment: OK, we know results but what is your input?

Comment: You don't need a function. They're already valid syntax so you can just type them as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
Double.valueOf("66e6");
```

Comment: I am not really sure about it. If I understand correctly `"66E6"` is output (result), not input.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I want.

Comment: Glad I could help. You could have been a LOT clearer in your question though, giving both inputs and outputs and making clear which is which!